# gvim on windows: file pointed to by tempname() does not exist

Tags: windows, vim

I'm trying to use a vim script that issues commands to sas, 
When i try to run the script i receive an error

"Can't open file ..path.. /AppData/Local/Temp/ .. temp file .. "

this is the path and file name returned by :tempname()

After navigating to the appdata temp files directory, the temp file does not exist.

I've tried manually changing the backup directory with set backupdir=~\tmp
(a directory I created) 
but that doesn't change the return value of :tempname() nor does the tempfile actually exist.

Two questions, 
1. Is there a way to ensure vim is writing the file the script seems to need
2. can i rewrite the script to avoid needing a temp file? (just pass the path to the actual file to sas?)

the relevant part of the script is

```
    let returntxt = system("\"" .
    \ shellescape("C:\\Program\ Files\\SAS\\SASFoundation\\9.2\\sas.exe") .
    \ "\ -nosplash" . "\ -sysin" . "\ " .
    \ shellescape(expand("%:p")) .  "\"") 

" Shows the return messages from the SAS commandline (may be useful
" if no log produced)
:echo "*** SAS commandline: " . returntxt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 'backupdir' contains a list of directories where backup files are generated, it has nothing to do with temporary directory (except that it *depends* on where it is located, opposite is not true). You should try using `%TMP%` or `%TEMP%` environment variable, either from vim using

```
let $TMP=expand('~/tmp')
```

or before vim is launched (don’t know how to do this on windows). Using `let $TMP` does work for me under wine, but only for existing temporary directories.

Note that your `system()` call is rather strange: `shellescape()` should already add all needed quotes so that surrounding `"\""` are not required (if it does not you should properly configure 'shell*' options). You also don’t need to escape spaces: `"\ "` and `" "` are exactly the same strings.

About second question: you can try passing file contents as a second argument to `system()`, but if file may contain NULLs it is not going to work.

Comment: I think there's a problem with powershell (windows 7) and shell escape?  "The term 'C:\Program' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program"  is returned to system()

Comment: at any rate, fixing the shell problem and properly setting a temp directory doesn't fix the problem.  Now vim complains the temp file doesnt exist in my new directory.  Navigating to that directory i find a file which is filename~  but vim is looking for a temp file with a name like 'VIo5B24.tmp'

Comment: @justincress If `shellescape('C:\Program Files\...')` does not work for powershell without using `"` it means that you should 1. update vim to the most recent version (if it is not) 2. if problem stays, complain to vim bug tracker (better to ask on #vim on freenode before the latter, maybe there is a powershell user there).

Comment: @justincress I don’t see how you are creating a temporary file so can’t say anything. The part you provided can’t be considered “relevant” without this detail.

Comment: I don't understand why I'm creating a temporary file either.  I changed the shell to 'cmd.exe' and now everything works.  Thanks for the help.